# I am having issues with ownCloud overwriting features

Tags: html, owncloud

I've been trying to figure out a way to disable file overwrites on my ownCloud.
The way it works currently is I send out a public upload link, for any user with a link to upload images. This is all well and good, until one of the images has the same name as another one. When this happens, I get this popup: [image]

This would be fine, if it wasn't meant to be a large repo with lots of pictures in it. The issue is, since it is a public upload link, I don't want other users images to be overwritten. If a user were to select JUST 'new files' it would overwrite the old one, which I could then revert, but in the instance that a user overwrites 500 files, I wouldn't want to go back and revert them one by one.

What I have tried so far is this: I found this file: fileexists.html which outlines that exact popup, and tried to edit it to where it automatically checks all the boxes and locks them.
Code in the file:

```
<div id="{dialog_name}" title="{title}" class="fileexists">
    <span class="why">{why}<!-- Which files do you want to keep --></span><br/>
    <span class="what">{what}<!-- If you select both versions, the copied file will have a number added to its name. --></span><br/>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <th><label><input class="allnewfiles" checked disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />{allnewfiles}<span class="count"></span></label></th>
        <th><label><input class="allexistingfiles" checked disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />{allexistingfiles}<span class="count"></span></label></th>
    </table>
    <div class="conflicts">
        <div class="template">
            <div class="filename"></div>
            <div class="replacement">
                <input checked disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="svg icon"></span>
                <div class="mtime"></div>
                <div class="size"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="original">
                <input checked disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="svg icon"></span>
                <div class="mtime"></div>
                <div class="size"></div>
                <div class="message"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried looking through the entire source, but can't find a way to do this.

Edit:
I found some more data indicating the values, but its javascript which I'm not too familiar with.

oc-dialogue.js:

```
    //add checkbox toggling actions
                    $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles').on('click', function() {
                        var $checkboxes = $(dialogId).find('.conflict .replacement input[type="checkbox"]');
                        $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                    });
                    $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles').on('click', function() {
                        var $checkboxes = $(dialogId).find('.conflict .original:not(.readonly) input[type="checkbox"]');
                        $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                    });
                    $(dialogId).find('.conflicts').on('click', '.replacement,.original:not(.readonly)', function() {
                        var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
                        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
                    });
                    $(dialogId).find('.conflicts').on('click', '.replacement input[type="checkbox"],.original:not(.readonly) input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
                        var $checkbox = $(this);
                        $checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
                    });
//update counters
                $(dialogId).on('click', '.replacement,.allnewfiles', function() {
                    var count = $(dialogId).find('.conflict .replacement input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
                    if (count === $(dialogId+ ' .conflict').length) {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles').prop('checked', true);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles + .count').text(t('core','(all selected)'));
                    } else if (count > 0) {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles').prop('checked', false);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles + .count').text(t('core','({count} selected)',{count:count}));
                    } else {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles').prop('checked', false);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allnewfiles + .count').text('');
                    }
                });
                $(dialogId).on('click', '.original,.allexistingfiles', function(){
                    var count = $(dialogId).find('.conflict .original input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
                    if (count === $(dialogId+ ' .conflict').length) {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles').prop('checked', true);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles + .count').text(t('core','(all selected)'));
                    } else if (count > 0) {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles').prop('checked', false);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles + .count')
                            .text(t('core','({count} selected)',{count:count}));
                    } else {
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles').prop('checked', false);
                        $(dialogId).find('.allexistingfiles + .count').text('');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I am wondering whether this issue would easier be solved on another level - for example, have one sub-folder for each user and therefore a separate upload link for each one. You could then write a script which copies or moves the files into a common folder and rename them automatically if they clash. The ownCloud web frontend just doesn't seem the right place for this kind of thing.

Comment: @FriendFX That doesn't work with the setup. The point of the site is to combine peoples image folders together to make one large image folder.